# How to change date to milliseconds ms sql server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to convert a date type in ms sql server to milliseconds here's what I've tried. I'm totally new to ms sql server and would appreciate someones help.

```
SELECT  datediff(ms,date(),a.ReportDate), a.Peak
from [RealTimeUsage] a
where exists(
    select top 10 * from 
    CustomerPortal.dbo.users b, CustomerPortal.dbo.UsersDevice c
    where (b.useridid = c.useridid) order by a.ReportDate 
)
```

Comment: And the problem is? How is the result of this different than what you expect/need?

Comment: The problem is that it does not show any milliseconds when I query run this query. It shows nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built function date() in sql-server. If you want the current date, try using getdate() function

SELECT  datediff(ms,getdate(),a.ReportDate), a.Peak 
FROM [RealTimeUsage] a 
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT TOP 10 * FROM 
    CustomerPortal.dbo.users b, CustomerPortal.dbo.UsersDevice c
    WHERE (b.useridid = c.useridid) ORDER BY a.ReportDate 
)

and DATEDIFF() syntax is
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
enddate would be third parameter and startdate would be second (In case you have given it by mistake)